# IsPresent() method in protractor always return True

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, ui-automation, typescript-typings

I have a condition to check that if element is present already I will return true and if not I will return false so based on this true and false return by IsPresent I will perform few actions.

Below is code:

```
settingPage.elements.disableOtdCommission.isPresent().then((flag) => {
            if (flag) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

But here I see even when the **disableOtdCommission** is not present in DOM its going to if block and returning true. So, basically if element is present or not its going to if block only and returning always true.

Please help me resolving this issue. I already visited for same issue in different platform but didn't get any proper solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some more code would be useful to provide more context. It's unclear what `settingPage` represents.

Comment: settingsPage is one of the Page object where "disableOtdCommission" locator is present.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `JavaScript` is a mysterious language when it comes to validating truthy values. I am not pro in `JavaScript` but I have done some tests on your code I can figure out what could be a problem.

Let's assign variable to the code that is written

```
const value = settingPage.elements.disableOtdCommission.isPresent().then((flag) => {
            if (flag) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Here we are expecting the value to be `true` or `false` but it is not boolean but it's a `promise`. If you `console.log(value)`, you will get something like this

```
ManagedPromise {
  flow_: <ref *1> ControlFlow {
    propagateUnhandledRejections_: true,
    activeQueue_: TaskQueue {
      name_: 'TaskQueue::112',
      flow_: [Circular *1],
      tasks_: [Array],
      interrupts_: null,
      pending_: null,
      subQ_: null,
      state_: 'new',
      unhandledRejections_: Set {}
    },
    taskQueues_: Set { [TaskQueue], [TaskQueue] },
    shutdownTask_: null,
    hold_: Timeout {
      _idleTimeout: 2147483647,
      _idlePrev: [TimersList],
      _idleNext: [TimersList],
      _idleStart: 1297,
      _onTimeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      _timerArgs: undefined,
      _repeat: 2147483647,
      _destroyed: false,
      [Symbol(refed)]: true,
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 42,
      [Symbol(triggerId)]: 41
    }
  },
  stack_: null,
  parent_: ManagedPromise {
    flow_: <ref *1> ControlFlow {
      propagateUnhandledRejections_: true,
      activeQueue_: [TaskQueue],
      taskQueues_: [Set],
      shutdownTask_: null,
      hold_: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 2147483647,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 1297,
        _onTimeout: [Function (anonymous)],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: 2147483647,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: true,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 42,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 41
      }
    },
    stack_: null,
    parent_: ManagedPromise {
      flow_: [ControlFlow],
      stack_: null,
      parent_: [ManagedPromise],
      callbacks_: [Array],
      state_: 'pending',
      handled_: true,
      value_: undefined,
      queue_: null
    },
    callbacks_: [ [Task] ],
    state_: 'pending',
    handled_: true,
    value_: undefined,
    queue_: null
  },
  callbacks_: null,
  state_: 'pending',
  handled_: false,
  value_: undefined,
  queue_: null
}
```

also if you test is truthy values by `console.log(value ? "test1" : "test2")`
you will get `test1` as output. Means `value` is `true` irrespective of whether `disableOtdCommission` is present or not.

===========

Now you want to check whether an element is present or not, you can simply use `expect`

```
expect(settingPage.elements.disableOtdCommission.isPresent()).toEqual(true);
```

the test will get passed if element present otherwise fail

Hope this will help you.

Happy Coding~